# ¿Cómo insertar muchas filas de Excel a una base de datos MySQL?

Tags: mysql, excel

Mis archivos en general son de tipo **.xlsx** (*Excel 2007* y superior) y tienen entre 50 mil y 500 mil filas. Digamos que necesito convertir la siguiente tabla en *Excel*:

```
|--------|-------|
| Valor  | Letra |
|--------|-------|
|   1    |   a   |
|   2    |   b   |
|   3    |   c   |
|--------|-------|
```

... al siguiente código:

```
INSERT INTO tabla VALUES ( '1', 'a' );
INSERT INTO tabla VALUES ( '2', 'b' );
INSERT INTO tabla VALUES ( '3', 'c' );
```

Importando *Excel* a *phpMyAdmin* suele dar muchos errores, he comprado y utilizado *SQLizer.is* pero tarda muchísimas horas en convertir un *Excel* de 70 mil filas a *SQL*. Actualmente utilizo *Navicat for MySQL*, pero no necesito todas sus funciones (ofrece muchísimas), sólo la de conversión.

Comment: Hola Lukas, esto entra en opion personal ya que cada uno desde su experiencia puede recomendar un programa u otro. Aqui se buscan preguntas concretas y objetivas, no sugerencias ni opiniones. Un saludo

Comment: Lo que se me ocurre es utilices php, existe una libreria para leer los archivos de Excel y ya en base a tus filas de tu hoja tomas los datos y mandas tu insert y lo ejecutas, te haces una interfaz con HTML y asi puede alimentar tu base de datos

Comment: Algo que puedes hacer es pasar el xls a cvs como paso intermedio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías utilizar la función de concatenar en el mismo Excel, para formar tus sentencias de insert, la función de concatenar quedaría algo asi:

```
=CONCATENATE("INSERT INTO tabla VALUES ('",A1, "',", "'", B1, "')")
```

Y ejecutar los `inserts` directo en tu manejador de BDs

[image: concatenar]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo recomendaría MySQL Workbench

Comment: gracias @lois6b por el formato del texto!

Comment: De nada ^^ aunque no acabo de entender tu respuesta. puedes explicarla mejor? Un saludo

Comment: va, dejame explicarla un poco mejor a ver si ayuda a @Lukas

Comment: pero que haces con la columna `C`? podrias hacer un `script.sql` para que añada los valores de esa columna y poder ejecutar la consulta no ?

Comment: sí así es, ya con las inserciones de la columna C haría un script de sql para ejecutarlo

Comment: Pues para una buena respuesta faltaria añadir como pasas esa columna a un `.sql`:D

Comment: Es una buena respuesta ya que resuelve mi problema, pero veo un otro problema: ¿Qué pasa si un valor tiene símbolo ' ? ¿Y las fechas que tienen que ser importables con timestamp? Busco una solución que convierta archivos muy grandes con 90 columnas y medio millón de filas (como hace el navicat) y esa solución ocuparía demasiado tiempo...